# Generating function on number of ways to purchase a bouquet with exactly 50 dollars

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

**There are two kinds of flowers in a shop. Roses cost 3 dollars each while carnations cost 2 dollars each. How many different kinds of bouquets can be bought with exactly 50 dollars?**

My solution:

We can purchase $1,2,3,...$ roses, each cost $3$ dollars which gives the choices $(1+x^3+x^6+...)$. Likewise we can choose $(1+x^2+x^4+...)$ carnations. We define our generating function as:

$G(x) = (1+x^2+x^4+...)(1+x^3+x^6+...)=(-1/(x^3-1))(-1/(x^2-1))=(x^2-1)^{-1}(x^3-1)^{-1}$

We are to count the number of combinations where the total cost is 50 dollars, hence we're looking for $[x^{50}]$.

How can one compute $[x^{50}]G(x)?$

Comment: Binomial series?

Comment: @saulspatz well, kind of unsure since it is the product of two binoms :s

Comment: Well, I don't know if it simplifies much, because I haven't written it out, but in one factor, the degrees are all even, and in the other they're multiples of $3$, so there aren't many ways to make $50$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use trusty partial fractions...

$\begin{align*}
[x^{50}] \frac{1}{(1 - x^2) (1 - x^3)}
   &=  [x^{50}] \left(
                   \frac{1}{3 (1 + x + x^2)}
                     + \frac{1}{4 (1 + x)}
                     + \frac{1}{4 (1 - x)}
                     + \frac{1}{6 (1 - x)^2}
                \right) \\
   &= [x^{50}] \frac{1 - x}{3 (1 - x^3)}
        + \frac{1}{4} \cdot (-1)^{50}
        + \frac{1}{4}
        + \frac{1}{6} \cdot \binom{-2}{50} \\
   &= \frac{1}{3} \cdot [x^{50}] \frac{1}{1 - x^3}
        - \frac{1}{3} \cdot [x^{49}] \frac{1}{1 - x^3}
        + \frac{1}{2}
        + \frac{1}{6} \cdot \binom{50 + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} \\
   &= 9 
\end{align*}$

The powers of $x$ that appear in $(1 - x^3)^{-1}$ are all multiples of 3, and neither 50 nor 49 qualify.